# Making a custom directory the git default?

Tags: git

When I created my repo and cloned it locally it is located:

```
C:\Users\xavier\Documents\GitHub\phpBudgetTool
```

But my project is located:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\phpBudgetTool
```

How can I make the above the default directory where GIT tracks changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not cloning directly into C:\xampp\htdocs\phpBudgetTool?

Or alternatively you can clone into C:\Users\xavies\Documents\GitHub\phpBudgetTool and set up a virtual Host in Apache which points to that directory.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to do that by setting DocumentRoot in c:\XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf

By default:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs
```

Change it to:

```
C:\Users\xavier\Documents\GitHub\phpBudgetTool
```